# FastReport.OpenSource.Data.MsSql can't reference FastReports.OpenSource

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0, fastreport, visual-studio-2022

I have an existing ASP.NET Core 5 MVC app which is built with .Net 5 in VS2022. I added the nuGet packages FastReport.OpenSource.Web (2021.4.15), FastReport.OpenSource (2021.4.15) and FastReport.OpenSource.Data.MsSql (2021.4.0).

However, the following code fails to compile:

```
var webReport = new FastReport.Web.WebReport();
var mssql = new FastReport.Data.MsSqlDataConnection();
mssql.ConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConn"); //1
webReport.Report.Dictionary.Connections.Add(mssql);                         //2
webReport.Report.Load("report.frx");
```

If I leave out lines 1 and 2, the program compiles and I can see the report.  But with these lines included, I got a compile error:

> Error CS0012: The type 'DataConnectionBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'FastReport, Version=2021.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ceb240df42bf6e8'.

However, `FastReport.dll` (which is FastReport.OpenSource), is included as a reference.

[image: Detail of solution showing inclusion of FastReport]

I'm implementing this from an example at [dotnetthoughts](https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-use-fastreport-open-source-in-aspnetcore/) where the author seems to have it working.

Is this because `FastReports.dll` is version 2021.4.15.0 but the error indicates it wants 2021.4.0.0 ??

Comment: I do report.Load("file.frx") and report..Dictionary.Connections.Count is ZERO. i.e. report.Load does not Load. What should I used instead of Load to LOAD the data  sources from the frx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastReports has released a new version (2022.1) that has fixed this issue.  Kudos to them for responding quickly.